# connect two tables without a proper foreignkey in crystal reports 2013

Tags: crystal-reports

I have two tables in a report.

One has a string field called product group which stores and array of values:

Table 0:

```
PRODUCT_GROUP
12,23,01,44
```

Table 1:

```
PRODUCT_CODE DESCRIPTION
12           "Sandles"
23           "High Heels"
01           "Runners"
```

The table that holds the description has a record for each product group code and can only be run when another field is a certain value, ie dept = "shoes".

My question is how will i link the tables if one is array and one is only string?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Post an example of the contents of the second table.

Comment: ok second table has product id and product description , has a record for each code above, ie: productcode = 12, description = "Sandles",  so instead of printing 12, 33, 01, 44 on the report , i would like to print Sangles, High Heels, Runners, - that make more sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution is to redesign your tables a bit:

Category:

```
ID  Description
1   "Runners"
12  "Sandles"
23  "High Heels"
```

Product:

```
ID  Name
1   "Pink sandles"
2   "Air runners"
```

Product Category:

```
ProductId CategoryId
1         12
2         1
```

This will allow you to join tables as you want.

Otherwise, you'll have to do something like this:

- use a subreport to create an associated array (two arrays: one for IDs; one for descriptions); pass these arrays to the main report via a shared variable
- create a formula to parse the comma-delimited string, then substitute a value in the description array, using the position of the ID stored in the ID array.

Comment: I have tried this and it works perfectly , thanks for your help